# What is the Brocha one says on Quiche

Tags: halacha, food, blessing

If one makes a Quiche with bread-dough, does it become Pas Habaah Bkisnin and the Brocha would be mzonos or not?

Comment: You might clarify "Brocha would be mzonos" with "under certain circumstances". `:-)`

Comment: And can you please define "bread dough". Do you mean dough that is used to make bread?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1818 and its answers.

Comment: @tom smith How does that compare with how it is normally made? Or is that how it is normally made? I'm asking because by saying "if ... with bread-dough" you imply that most quiches are made with quiche dough(?). Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Halachos of Brochos (by Rabbi Yisroel Pinchos Bodner):

Broccoli, Mushroom, and Spinach Quiches are Mezonos (and the mezonos also exempts the filling).

As for the Bracha Achrona: It's Al Hamichya if a K'zayis of crust was eaten in K'dei Achilas Pras. If not, Borei Nefashos [provided there was shiur when combining with filling]. And if one was Koveah Seudah on it, Hamotzi and Birchas Hamazon are required.

---

As to whether the case brought down in the sefer is the same case as your described `Quiche with bread-dough`, I cannot tell. But at face-value they appear to be the same, assuming of course that the method you described is how a typical quiche is made. If it is not, please describe the difference, so we can further assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the recipe? It could give a clearer picture as to what kind of quiche we're dealing with.

If the Quiche has a crust, you would make a mezonot, as in [yydl's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9644/what-is-the-brocha-one-says-on-quiche/10075#10075) answer - unless the crust is made from whole pieces of bread.

As for Quiche filling without crust:

- If the main part of the quiche (a cake) is eggs (like most quiches), then it is a shahakol.
- If this is a special bread-like quiche, with lots of flour, it could be a mezonos.(Brochos 37b)
- If you eat so much of the hypothetical 'mezonos-quiche', that you make a meal out of it, you should make hamotze (Brachos 42a)

Related:

Quiche filling made from bread: (Brochos 37a)

- If the bread pieces are larger than a ke'zayit - hamotze
- If the bread pieces are less than a ke'zayit - mezonot

Also, 
If the quiche has recognizeable slices of vegetables, and it's not a hamotze or mezonot, you may need a haadamah as well.

Comment: According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiche), they have pastry doughs. How can it be a shehakol then?

Comment: You're right, I wasn't taking the pie-crust into account, just the filling. I'll adjust my answer to specify.

Comment: bread pieces not whole: SHEHAKOL?? // "haadamah as well" - well probably not if mezonos since kol sheyesh bo.

Comment: Goood catch. Shehakol? I don't know what I was thinking there.