# Can one make hamotzi Friday night on pat haba bekisnin?

Tags: shabbat, challah-shabbat-bread, hamotzi-beracha

Within [This article](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108010457W-29%20Pizza%20and%20Kevias%20Seuda.pdf) that focuses mainly on the bracha made on pizza, it mentions that most poskim state that when one eats *pat haba bekisnin* as a meal, one says *Hamotzi*.

Friday night meal requires *lechem Mishnah* (two "rolls"). Does it specifically require "bread" (something that is definitely hamotzi at all times) or may one use *pat haba bekisnin* as well?

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80046/9215

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68778/

Comment: Isn't this what most of us do on Pesach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *psak* of *Shemiras Shabbos KeHilchoso*: If one is *kovei'a* the meal on *pas habo'oh bekisnin,* for example, cake, then one can use two full cakes for *lechem mishneh.*

> **שמירת שבת כהלכתה פרק נה סעיף טז**:
>   הקובע סעודה על פת הבאה בכיסנין דהיינו עוגה יכול הוא לקחת שתי עוגות שלמות ללחם-משנה ולבצוע עליהן

Answer (score 1):

**din.org.il** was posed a related  question (in Hebrew) titled:  "[Kiddush on Shabbos on Pas Haba B'kisnin](http://din.org.il/2016/09/02/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A4%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F/)"

- The question:

> Greetings.
> In a pressing situation if there isn't wine or bread, is one allowed to make kiddush on pas ha ba b'kisnin?

- **din.org.il**'s answer:

> בדיעבד אפשר לקדש גם על פת הבאה בכיסנין – עוגה, ואף אם לא יקבע עליה סעודה נראה שאינו מעכב.
>
> B'dieved one could make kiddush on Pas Haba B'kisnin- cake, and even if one doesn't isn't kovea a meal on it it would appear that it doesn't prevent [one from fulfilling their obligation]

The sources cited for this ruling are:

> **שמירת שבת כהלכתה** פרק נג סעיף ז, ומקורו **בשו”ת יביע אומר** ח”ג סי’ יט **ושו”ת רבבות אפרים** ח”א סי’ רא, וראה שש”כ שם סעי’ יח שטוב לקבוע סעודתו על העוגה באופן זה, אבל אינו מעכב.
>
> **Shmirat Shabbat K'Hilchasa** *perek* 53 *si'if* 7, **Shu"t Yabia Omer** *cheilek* 3 *siman* 19, **Shu"t Rivivos Ephraim** *cheilek* 1 *siman* 201, and see there written in **siman** 18 that "it's good to *kovea* one's meal in this manner and it doesn't hold one back

### Application of this ruling to Lechem Mishnah

One could perhaps extend **din.org.il**'s ruling to your question.
If one is able to fulfill their Kiddush obligation-- which many believe is on a d'oraisa level (**Rambam**, [Hilchos Shabbos 29:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbath.29.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), see also [Mishnah Berurah 271:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.271.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))-- via the use of *pas haba b'kisnin*,
all the more so the obligation for Lechem Mishnah-- which virtually everyone says is d'rabanan (besides the **Taz** [OC 678:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.678.1?lang=bi&p2=Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.678.2&lang2=bi) -- but even his opinion can mean d'rabanan- see [here](https://tvunah.org/%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94/))-- can be fulfilled with *pas haba b'kisnin*.

Comment: Your logic doesn't follow at all. Kiddush Deorayta can be fulfilled without any food. Lechem mishna is a rule about food. It's also predicated on the assumption that whether one can use pat HaBa BeKisnin has to do with how strict an obligation you are trying to fulfill. I don't understand why that would be.

Answer (score 0):

I once asked my Rebbe about making Hamotzi on Friday night on a substantial amount of Cheerios (also Pas Haba Bekisnin). I was told specifically not to - not that it’s better not to, but that I shouldn’t do it at all. He did not give a reason.

Comment: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2006/07/korach-minyan-this-past-shabbos_04.html but anyway it's not obvious that Cheerios has תוריתא דנהמא to ever be able to say Hamotzi

Comment: This answer would be much more valuable to others if it would include your Rebbe's name

Comment: Why do you think that Cheerios are Pas Haba Bekisnin? Because they look like mini-bagels??

Comment: @DannySchoemann Why shouldn’t they be Pas Haba Bekisnin? They fit the third definition in SA OC 168:7.