# Which Bracha do you make on Calzones?

Tags: halacha, blessing

In [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/washing-hands-for-eating-pizza?rq=1) question there are various opinions regarding pizza and the Bracha you make on it. How should one view Calzones? Furthermore, is it considered a Memula similar to Pashtida (OC 168:17)?

Comment: What is a "Memula"? Please [edit] to clarify and/or dejargonify.

Comment: Note most of the variant opinions listed there are just historical oddities at this point. Nowadays pizza is for sure regular Hamotzi since it is generally treated as a meal-food in our society (see socio-culinary data at http://www.wherewhatwhen.com/article/a-usda-study-helps-clarify-halacha).

Comment: What do you mean "is it similar to Pashtida"? It _is_ a Pashtida. That's precisely what the Shulchan Arukh that you cited says! What is unclear to you that you need to ask?

Answer (score 6):

According to [OU](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/correct-bracha-pizza/https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/correct-bracha-pizza/), there is a dispute on this:

> The bracha on calzones and the like, filled with cheese or meat (known
>   as “pashtida” in the language of the poskim), is not as clear. A fruit
>   pie is a Mezonos because it is a dessert item, while calzones are
>   often intended to be the main meal and not dessert. Although the Taz
>   (168:20) rules that the bracha on calzones is Mezonos, the Shulchan
>   Aruch (168:17), and Mishna Berura (168:94) rule that the bracha is
>   Hamotzi. However, the Biur Halacha states that many Achronim agree
>   with the Taz, and if the calzone is clearly not meant as a main-meal
>   type of food, the bracha is definitely Mezonos. Rav Belsky, zt”l said
>   that it is unclear whether pizza is a snack or meal food, but noted
>   that the general custom is to say Mezonos when eating a small amount.

In view of what DoubleAA mentioned in the comment above, my thinking is that calzones are usually eaten as a meal, and I think that would, thus, qualify it as *Hamotzi*. This is an area to ask your rav. I'd like to know his answer. I'm hoping that the answer is **not** "I'm not sure. Why don't you eat a piece of challah first?"

Comment: It is incorrect to claim, in this context, that the Shulchan Aruch rules the bracha is hamotzi - that is part of the disagreement between the Taz and the M.B.! The Taz says the S.A. is talking specifically about a case where he was koveia seudah, but otherwise it would be mezonos.

Comment: @jay it is correct to say it because if you read the shulchan arukh that's what he says. The Taz is adding to the text. Maybe it'd be better to clarify "on the straightforward reading" but it's hardly incorrect

Comment: @DoubleAA that's why I said 'in this context' - in the context of the disagreement between the M.B. and the Taz, to imply as is done here that the S.A. sides with either one is incorrect, as they are arguing over what case the S.A. is talking about. To say the S.A. sides with the M.B. is to already assume that the Taz is wrong about the S.A.'s opinion.

Comment: @jay which is correct because the straightforward read of the ShA is indeed that the Taz is wrong about the ShA's opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are from NY people consider Pizza to be a snack and therefore they say mezonos on it (minhag hamakom?). So I would assume Calzones there would be of a similar nature as it is basically the same food. 
On the West Coast people say hamotzei over both...

Comment: Are you from New York? How often do you eat pizza as a snack?

Comment: Hi Imma, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I am from NY, and from what I have seen, most people who either go out for pizza or bring it home are making a meal of just pizza. It is often supper for the family. This is almost definitely true when having an "individual" (like those 5 or 6" mini) pies. But even with the one or two slices, most have that as a meal. I would probably qualify the traditional Motzaei Shabbat pizza as a "melavah malka" meal. I'm not sure that *minhag hamakom* is a factor, here, anyway. The halach appears to be individual behavior.

Comment: The definition of "snack" is "a small amount of food eaten **between** meals". It's debatable what a "small amount of food" means in terms of quantity or volume. But, from what I have seen, most are not having a slice **between** meals. It **is** the meal.

Comment: I have lived in both NY and elsewhere ("out of town", multiple places out of NY actually). There was a high percentage of people who ate pizza in Brooklyn, NY I knew who thought it weird I washed and benched. They all made mezonos and al hamichiya on it. No one I know in my community now DOESNT wash. My response was based off my experience in multiple cities.

Comment: @imma but did any of them treat it as a snack culinarily? or just said that to get a Halakhic leniency?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure where you have been living. I can vouch for the fact that within the NY area, at least, pizza brachot halacha has changed within the past 20 - 30 years. When I was in YU High School, we were told that pizza was a "snack" and you make mezonot unless you ate more than two slices. In that case, you had to wash and say Hamotzi.  (I don't quite understand that quantity limit applied to pizza.) When my kids were in elementary school about 10 years ago, they had numerous pizza parties, and even for 1 slice, they were told to wash and say Hamotzi.

Comment: @DanF It's not just the Halakha that changed. The facts on the ground ("Metziut") has changed too. Pizza in the USA is now overwhelmingly a meal food. People don't snack on it anymore. 75 years ago it was more normal to eat a piece of pizza as a snack. See http://www.unico.org/pdf/The_History_of_Pizza.pdf "There is no doubt that Italian immigrants brought pizza to the United States as part of
their culture from the Old World. Italians generally saw pizza as a snack, not as a meal.... Pizza became very popular in the United States after World War II."

Comment: I would be inclined to upvote this, but, I would like to see some source supporting the notion that *minhag hamakom* would be a factor in deciding the bracha. My last comment merely states what I have seen occur, thus, supporting what you stated. I inherently have *emunat chachamim*, so, I don't question a halachic decision emanating from either my school rebbe or my kids' rebbeim. But, on a hunch, I don't think that their decision was based on *minhag hamakom*.

Comment: @DoubleAA "Pizza in the USA is now overwhelmingly a meal food. " Can I infer from this statement that *minhag hamakom* is a factor in deciding the bracha?

Comment: @DanF A food's culinary role in that location is a factor. Not unlike if a certain fruit is generally eaten raw or not there. If you want to call that _minhag hamakom_ then so be it.