# Another pizza bracha question

Tags: blessing, food, hamotzi-beracha

We have several "pizza bracha" questions on this site, but, I will focus on a specific item on [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1819/5275). Excerpts:

> 1.The opinion of Harav Moshe Feinstein zt”l holds two slices makes you responsible to wash.(I believe this would be the Main Psak (Halachic
>   Ruling) for American's)

I'm thinking that at the time Rav Moshe said this, he was referring to the "standard" dough thickness and the standard pie diameter which, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York-style_pizza) is 14 in. in diameter. (I am terrible at trigonometry, so, I don't know how to calculate that into what the volume of 2 triangles would be.) There weren't too many kosher pizza stores in the NY area and, from my recollection, NY style pizza was the only style available.

Now, kosher pizza stores sell different pizza styles. Besides Sicilian (answer to that is addressed in the linked answer), there is thin crust, Chicago pan pizza (thick crust) and probably a few other styles I can't think of. The pizza pies also come in different sizes.

Given all these options, my question, here, is has anyone compiled a revised ruling regarding how much one can eat (assuming following the rulings that distinguish amounts between "snack" vs. a meal. I know there are rulings that don't make this distinction.) before he would be required to wash and say "hamotzi" that addresses the various pizza styles? Obviously, all this is related to the volume of dough that's consumed, but, has anyone related these styles to the "triangle" concept ("piece") as above?

Comment: Did you try taking two such slices and weighing them, and use that weight to determine the status of other pizzas?

Comment: @Ploni Well, OK. That system certainly would give the answer. It also would require research and eating / purchasing a large amount of pizza. I might be willing to conduct this experiment.

Comment: The revised ruling is R Moshe would never say that today. Mezonos on pizza is obsolete, and just some people haven't caught on because it's too inconvenient for them.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm a bit vague on that last comment. Is that basing thing sonly on Rav Moshe's ruling as it applies today, or is there an overall ruling that no one should be saying mezonot on pizza regardless of size, type or quantity? If it's the latter, can you post that as an answer? Perhaps, you did that, already, in which case it may be in some other MY question that I couldn't find. Shabbat Shalom.

Comment: @DanF R' Moshe held that pizza was a snack food and not something people would eat as a meal. People don't really eat pizza that way anymore.

Comment: @DanF Indeed see my comment on the answer you linked to which has the data to support Daniel's point

Comment: @DoubleAA and @ Daniel I thought the difference in opinions on pizza were based on whether it is pas habah bkisnin, not whether it is a snack food.

Comment: @sah how a food is treated culinarily may affect its status as PHBK (at least in whats commonly presented as r moshe's opinion)