# Mizuman on Pizza

Tags: halacha, blessing, zimun

There is a well known discussion about the proper brocho to make on pizza. Say three people are eating pizza at the same table. One washes on his pizza and the other two make a mezonos. Can the person who washed make a mezuman with the other two?

Comment: It may depend on if you think the other two are holding of a valid opinion (and there's no daas to mitztaref) or if you think they are straight up [mistakenly relying on an out-of-date application of an old opinion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/washing-hands-for-eating-pizza/1819#comment196904_1819) (and they're no different from a lazy person who skips brachas entirely)

Comment: See SA OC 197:3. It would seem that you would need at least two who washed and are bentching and then the third who is making Al hamichya can be metzaref